# Localized Display attribute with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, data-annotations, displayname-attribute

In the resource file we defined some strings with parameters, e.g. `userDefinedX: User Defined {0}`.

My question is - is there any way to incorporate that parameter into

`Display[Name = "userDefinedX", ResourceType = typeof("Labels")]` syntax? The only solution we currently come up with was to introduce new string for each user defined field (1,2,3) in our case. Attribute does not allow to insert variables in them.

Comment: what language is this? is this C# and asp.net MVC or something else?

Comment: Sorry, added more tags. It's C# and ASP.NET MVC application with angularJs